# Web application does not deploy correctly after upgrade to macOS High Sierra

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, macos-high-sierra

I have a web application that had been running fine in Tomcat 8 under macOS Sierra. However, I recently upgrade to high sierra, and the application then failed to deploy. The following log is seen in the catalina.out,

```
11-Jan-2018 14:43:02.288 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
11-Jan-2018 14:43:02.306 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/connect] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Then the stack trace of an endless loop on logger with the stackoverflow error seen in the localhost.log, as the following. The error gives no clue as what the problem is (for example beans are not properly wired etc.), making it extremely difficult to troubleshoot.

```
11-Jan-2018 14:43:02.288 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending 
context initialized event to listener instance of class 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
```

Has anyone seen this problem?

Thanks for any tips you can offer.

Comment: After another look at the stack trace and it seemed to indicate a logger related dependency cycle issue, ie. log4j -> slf4j -> log4j. I then checked the logger related jar files in the web application's lib, and I found both "log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar" and "slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar". I then removed "slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar", things started to work!  I am glad to have the issue fixed, but I am still puzzled as why this worked before the upgrade to High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I would try - Clean install of the project, Clean tomcat work directory. Check versions of JARs to see if there is any mismatch!